# Can i sync my vscode to my termux terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, termux

i installed VHEditor on my android, which is typically the android version of VScode, but when I tried using the integrated terminal, I can't see what I'm typing. Anything I type won't show in the integrated terminal, and now I want to switch terminal by using my termux terminal instead of the integrated terminal in vscode.

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem while using **VHEditor** **[***I can't see what I'm typing. Anything I type won't show in the integrated terminal***]**.

This issue is already posted on github, Visit here --> [Cannot see letters on terminal #196](https://github.com/vhqtvn/VHEditor-Android/issues/196)

If the letters in the terminal are not visible then just change this settings.

- Go to settings and search for `Terminal Integrated GPU`
- Change this settings from `auto` to `off`

[image: Image of VHEditor settings]

> Terminal > Integrated > Gpu Acceleration Preference of VScode to *Off*.

You don't need *termux* to use **VHEditor**, because it has an inbuilt *termux*.